# Electron: Share <webview> Tag content using desktopCapture with WebRTC as a video stream

Tags: webview, electron, webrtc

I have a WebView inside a BrowserWindow. Webview acts as a embedded browser.
I want to do a screenshare using WebRTC, where only my WebView gets shared.

Does anyone know, what the event desktop-capturer-get-sources https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-desktop-capturer-get-sources
is for?

Comment: Please help if anyone has any solution as to how can this be implemented.
or if we can do some workaround.

Comment: are you using electron.js?

Comment: it has resolved?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using electron.js to build your desktop application, you can go through this example provided by electron official document

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer#desktopcapturergetsourcesoptions-callback.

the output will behave the same as any audio/video stream use in webrtc

Comment: I have tried that already, a webview is not considered as a desktopCaptureSource, https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/desktop-capturer-source
and hence the api is not returning it as a source

Comment: Are you using electron.js to make desktop application from your angular client source ?

Comment: I am using electron.js
With no framework, I am only using basic vanilla javascript.